# Ordered list in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

How configurate IntelliJ IDEA so that the numbered list in code looks like this:

```
1. abc
1. dfg
1. ...
```

Now the numbered list looks like:

```
1. abc
2. dfg
3. ...
```

It need for see normal different in Git

I used markdown for write document. But I can't configurate it

For example, how it looks like in VScode (editor / preview)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkqWF.png

Comment: Please provide a couple of screenshots showing the expected/actual result. At the moment it is not fully clear what result you'd like to achieve, as the expected/actual result in the issue description looks the same.

Comment: added to description

Comment: Okay, and what's the problem with how it's rendering?

Comment: Problem is that now i used Intelegent Idea, and list in editor look like another. (1. ,2., 3. ...).  And when you added new item in list, it can  changed numeration. When Git compared changed - I see more changes what was. In VScode it not problem, because when you added item in list it have number 1. (always). and in Git we see changed what we do

Comment: You're referring to the source code, not the rendered result? You wish to use `1.` for each number instead of `1.`, `2.`, and so on? I guess IntelliJ automatically types the next letter when you press Enter?

Comment: yep, right. I found how deactivate automatically numeration. But it not for me